# making trigrams from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to find matched elements in a second column with the first column of a data frame ,and create a trigrams using the matched element as the middle element of the trigram. In case of no match, the middle and last element of the trigram will be the unmatched second-column element. Here is an example:

```
gdf <- data.frame(from=c(1,2,3,4,5),to=c(2,3,1,5,6),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
gdf
# from   to
#    1    2
#    2    3
#    3    1
#    4    5
#    5    6
```

The output trigrams are as follow:

```
from middle to
   1      2  3
   2      3  1
   3      1  2
   4      5  6
   5      6  6
```

My code with for loop takes a long time to process my huge data set.my data set has 54304 rows.

This is what I wrote:

```
num <- nrow(gdf) 
df2 <- data.frame(from=character(0),middle=character(0),to=character(0),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
count <- rep(0,nrow(gdf))
for(row in 1:nrow(gdf)){ 
  for(rowc in 1:nrow(gdf)){  
    if(gdf[rowc,]$from==gdf[row,]$to){ 
      df2[nrow(df2)+1,]<-c(gdf[row,]$from,gdf[row,]$to,gdf[rowc,]$to)  
      count[row]<-row 
    } 
  } 
  if(count[row]==0){ 
    df2[nrow(df2)+1,]<-c(gdf[row,]$from,gdf[row,]$to,gdf[row,]$to) 
  } 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your example is too simple for this to work in the real data set, but a simple merge works for the example and then I sort the columns to get them back in order since a merge places the column that you merge by as column 1.

```
Merged <- merge(gdf,gdf,by.x="to",by.y="from")[,c(2,1,3)]
```

Then you can add in the nomatch elements later using a row bind

```
rbind(Merged,gdf[! paste(gdf[,1],gdf[,2]) %in% paste(Merged[,1],Merged[,2]),][,c(1,2,2)])
```

Comment: give the answer a tick then so that the question gets closed